# Fix KeyError: '\\s' when trying to replace a substring with one that includes special characters with re.sub() or re.subn() method

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, special-characters, keyerror

```py
import re

input_text = "Hello!, How are you? "

#input_text = re.sub(" ", r"[\s|-|]", input_text)
input_text, nro_repl = re.subn(' ', r'[\s|-|]', input_text)

print(repr(input_text))
print(repr(nro_repl))
```

The correct output:

```
4
'Hello!,[\s|-|]How[\s|-|]are[\s|-|]you?[\s|-|]'
```

The error that I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    this = chr(ESCAPES[this][1])
KeyError: '\\s'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
    raise s.error('bad escape %s' % this, len(this))
re.error: bad escape \s at position 1
```

How do I fix this error and get the desired result, managing to have the input string but making the replacements by substrings with the special characters?

Comment: From the [manual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub): "repl can be a string or a function; if it is a string, any backslash escapes in it are processed. That is, \n is converted to a single newline character, \r is converted to a carriage return, and so forth. Unknown escapes of ASCII letters are reserved for future use and treated as errors"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [manual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) that @Nick posted it tells us that there will be no backslash escape processing of the replacement if we pass a function instead of a string. So all you have to do is replace the string argument with a lambda returning the string.

```py
import re

input_text = "Hello!, How are you? "
input_text, nro_repl = re.subn(' ', lambda x: '[\s|-|]', input_text)

print(repr(nro_repl))
print(repr(input_text))
```

output:

```
4
'Hello!,[\\s|-|]How[\\s|-|]are[\\s|-|]you?[\\s|-|]'
```

Comment: Really thanks for the help! I didn't know you could do it with a lambda argument.